# Overriding left style with CSS

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I am trying to change the position of a side panel that comes up when an option is being hovered over. Here is the code from chrome developer tools:

```
<nav id= "side_nav" class= "sidebar-bg-color header-side-nav-scroll-show">
    <ul data-template= "nav-template" class= "sidebar-bg-color ps-ready ps-container" data-blind= "source: nodes">
        <li class= "nav_trigger nav_open">
            <div class= "sub_panel" style= "left: 50px;"> == $0
            </div>
        </li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

I just need to change that style `left : 50px` to `76px`. The developer tools just have this attribute saved under `element.style` which I can't really target in my CSS file. Any help is appreciated!

I have tried to target by being really specific and ended up targeting the main panel and not the sup panel.  Here is the code that I tried:

```
nav #side_nav, ul.sidebar-bg-color ps-ready ps-container, li.nav_trigger nav_open, div.sub_panel{ 
left : 76px; 
},
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your CSS selector should be as shown below (according to the HTML you posted). Look at every detail: I deleted all commas and a few spaces. If an element has more than one class, you address it like `div.class1.class2` (no spaces, but with a dot between the class names). Commas are used to list *separate* selectors for the same rule, *not* to indicate child elements as you did. To select an element which has as ID, you directly attach the ID to the element (Not `nav #side_nav`, but `nav#side_nav`).

```
nav#side_nav ul.sidebar-bg-color.ps-ready.ps-container li.nav_trigger.nav_open, div.sub_panel { 
  left : 76px; 
}
```

If necessary, add `!important` after `76px` (but before the semicolon).

Comment: That worked, thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

You can use the syntax `!important` so then it will override all other formating of the type that you use the `!important` on. Learn more here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/Building_blocks/Cascade_and_inheritance#!important

You can also use the `span` element in the HTML to make it even more specific with the CSS.

Comment: The problem with that is that I can't target the element correctly to be able to use !important.

Comment: I changed what my answer says added some other stuff you can use.